# Is there a way to do a file.rename while doing a file.copy in R for directories?

Tags: r

I'm trying to move files from one folder to the next but also rename them while in transition and for the final product.

```
file.copy(file.path(Main_Directory,DailyFolders), 
to = New_Directory,overwrite= TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
```

Note that I have a list of old files

```
c("Style_1","Style_2","Style_3")
```

I would like to see the folder names become

```
c("MoreStyle_1","MoreStyle_2","MoreStyle_3")
```

I don't want to move the files and then change the name after they are in the folder with say `file.rename()` . I want to move the files and change the name before it shows up in file explorer.

Comment: Are `"Style_1"`, etc filenames or directory names?

Comment: They are directory names. I meant to say to just change the directory names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the directory structure this is a shot in the dark.
Get the old file names with `list.files(., full.names = TRUE)`. Then substitute the new folder names for the old ones.
`file.rename` should now work.

```
DailyFolders <- c("Style_1","Style_2","Style_3")
New_Folders <- c("MoreStyle_1","MoreStyle_2","MoreStyle_3")

Old_Directory <- file.path(Main_Directory, DailyFolders)
old_names <- list.files(path = Old_Directory, pattern = "*.*", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

new_names <- old_names
for(i in seq_along(DailyFolders)) {
  new_names <- sub(DailyFolders[i], New_Folders[i], new_names)
}

file.rename(old_names, new_names)
```

Comment: doesn't this change the name in the original folder? I want it to change in the new folder while keeping the original names in the old directory.

Comment: @user35131 Yes, it does. If the new folders already exist, change to `file.copy`. And if you don't want duplicate files in the old and new folders, `file.remove(old_names)` after copying.

Comment: I get permission denied for some reason.

Comment: @user35131 Which of the operations gives you permission denied? Any way, that's a problem in your system, not of R code.

Comment: I found another alternative instead of ```file.remove```, instead i used ```unlink(). Otherwise it worked out. Thank you.